# How to submit a form on change with a function callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit a form on change if they select a file, but when I submit it doesn't run the function callback for my ajax;;

```
$(function(){

    $("#page_photo").on("change", function() {

        alert("1st stage"); 

        $('#image_upload').trigger("submit", function(){

        alert("2nd stage");

            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>image/upload_user_photo',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if(!data.success){
                        $.notify(data.error, "error");
                    }else{
                        $.notify(data.success, "success");
                    }
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            return false;
        }); 
    });
});
```

I don't want the user to have to press the submit button before it submits, just when they select the file, so `.submit` won't wor for this

Comment: what do you think trigger("submit", function(){}) is doing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind your submit callback with the following syntax:

```
$('#image_upload').bind("submit", function(){
    alert("2nd stage");
});
```

Then trigger the submit event with the following code:

```
$('#image_upload').trigger("submit");
```

Comment: Take my likes :) Will submit for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like below. How to exactly get the uploaded file depends a bit on your HTML, but if you can get the data correctly there's no need to fire a submit, you can simply fire off your AJAX call whenever the change happens.

```
$(function(){

    $("#page_photo").on("change", function() {

        alert("1st stage"); 
        //BELOW MIGHT NEED TO BE CHANGED TO CORRECTLY GET THE IMAGE
        var formData = new FormData($('#image_upload')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>image/upload_user_photo',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if(!data.success){
                    $.notify(data.error, "error");
                }else{
                   $.notify(data.success, "success");
                }
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to submit the form though because that passes the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` over.